# Is there a way to pass GPS coordinates to a map displayed in a webview?

Tags: android, dictionary, webview, gps

I have a very simple android application displaying this URL :

http://www.ahuzot.co.il/Map/Parking/

in a simple webview display.
it just displayes the map via a webview.

Is there any way to use the  phone's GPS and pass cooardinates to this particular map ?
in order to enable the user to locate himself on the map?

thanks in advance

Comment: That is Google map. Use Google Map api instead of webview.

Answer (score 1):

From this code, adapt it to your needs ;)

Main.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/webview1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webview.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        openURL();
    }

    private void openURL() {
        webview.loadUrl('http://www.ahuzot.co.il/Map/Parking/');
        webview.requestFocus();
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              view.loadUrl(url);
              return true;
          }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** 
Now, if you have access to the source code of the web application what you have to do is enable a javascript method on the web app (i.e. locateOnMap) that receives as a parameter the latitude and longitude you want to locate on the map. This method should be responsible for updating the map with the new location. After you have loaded the map, invoke webview's *loadUrl* method again. Below an example of the invocation:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:locateOnMap('37.3833', '-5.9833');
```

Comment: Hi

The problem is I don't want to use it directly with google website .
look at the URL: http://www.ahuzot.co.il/Map/Parking/
it has additional information in the map there about parking places.
displayed on the map, and if I use you're code I will not display that information...
Please help me if there is anyway to make this work.

Comment: I am not sure I have access to the source code.
It is not my website.
How can I check if I have access to the javascript source code ? 
the URL is:
http://www.ahuzot.co.il/Map/Parking/
thank you

Comment: Obviously you need access to the source code of the application to write the method that I wrote before. 'How can I check if I have access to the javascript source code?'. Well, if you have not developed the application definitely you can not use the method that I comment earlier and you'll have to find another solution.

Comment: I have not developed the application of this website.
Is there another solution you can think of ?

Comment: I have not developed the application of this website. Is there another solution you can think of ??

Comment: @nimrod99 A bit outdated comment, but... You can try to reverse-engineer the website and try to get requests that give the marker positions and properties. (Tel Aviv parking map for android would be great, yeah...)